# Half screen semi circle on left

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to create a semi circle like the following with css?

[image: semi circle]

If yes, can someone explain me how to do it or where can I find some tutorials to learn?
My Menu and Footer are already in place. I just want to know how to draw semi circles similar to that ones and, the application can run in different screen sizes and the image of the semi circles should adapt to the screen size

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid class="semi-circle">
        
    </v-container>
</template>
<style>
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.semi-circle {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #505c7b;
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0;
  box-shadow: inset -3.5rem 1px 0 #7d869c, 
                    3.5rem 1px 0 #bec2cd;
}


</style>
```

and my result:

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? shouldn't be to hard with pseudo-elements and absolute or fixed positioning.

Comment: Try with CSS view port unit like view port width or percent: https://web.dev/viewport-units/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, I've tested it, and I've also **commented** on the lines that I've changed. (3 lines)

Hope it helps you!

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}

.semi-circle {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1; /* 1:1 aspect-ratio, so the height we specified in the next line and width, becomes the same */
  height: 100vh; /* 100vh means the entire height of the viewport (viewport means the area which can be "viewed" */
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* using translateX we can move the circle, in the "X" axis (i.e., left-right direction), -50% of its size (negative to move it to the left), so half of the circle gets moved out of the screen */ 
  background: #505c7b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset -3.5rem 1px 0 #7d869c, 
                    3.5rem 1px 0 #bec2cd;
}
```

```html
<div class="semi-circle"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. aspect-ration was what I was missing. I was almost there :b with your help its done 100% thanks

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.semi-circle {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 20rem;
  background: #505c7b;
  border-radius: 0 10rem 10rem 0;
  box-shadow: inset -1.5rem 1px 0 #7d869c, 
                    1.5rem 1px 0 #bec2cd;
}
```

```html
<div class="semi-circle"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, that helped me. Im sorry but this are my first steps with front :b how can I put the image like half screen? sorry